# Simulate keyboard typing without using SendKeys

Tags: c#, .net

I have a random text, which can include special (for sendkeys) symbols like ), ( etc (obvious book, for example). Screening unsuitable too, becouse string send through the internet, so the size of string important. Can you suggest some decision?

Comment: Why is SendKeys not an option?

Comment: Beсouse i get a exceptions, when trying to type something like "Hi guys)". This string contains special symbols.

Comment: Perahps you would do better to show your hi guys code, rather than reinvent the wheel, we maybe able to help you fix it

Comment: "`invalid string SendKeys "ghj &+)"` System.ArgumentException"


. My code:
`public void TypeCustomMessage(string message)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait(message);
           
        }`

Comment: I've tried to use "SendKeys.Send(string)", but it does not work too

Comment: You have to escape certain characters. For example brackets should be escaped like this: `Hi guys{)}`. See the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if your problems go away:

```
public void TypeCustomMessage(string message)
{
    SendKeys.SendWait(Regex.Replace(message, @"(\+|\^|%|~|\(|\)|\[|]|\{|})", "{$1}"));
}
```

Comment: Thanx) Looks like this solution works fine!